# Won't go into prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, server, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert something into my table called user. I have checked the names of the columns and it is correct, but it doesn't seem to go through the prepared statement as none of my echo messages shows up.
I am using a password hash, but have made sure the varchar is "big" enough.
It worked on the localhost, but not when I uploaded it to a server.

```js
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if($stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, username, password, mail, joined) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?, NOW())")){
    echo "hello banana";
    $stmt -> bind_param("sssss",$_POST["firstname"], $_POST["lastname"], $_POST["username"], $password, $_POST["email"]);
    $stmt -> execute();
    echo "hello fruit";
    $id = $stmt -> insert_id;
    $stmt -> store_result();
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
    $redirectIndex = 1;
    $message =  "Account registered. You can now go to the <a href=\"index.php\"> front page</a>.";
     
    
    $stmt -> close(); 
}
```

Comment: You can't use `$store_result()` for an `INSERT` statement, there's no result set.

Comment: `$conn->prepare()` will return false on error, check that. If it is false, check `mysqli_error()` or equivilent.

Comment: Add `else { echo $conn->error; }` to see the reason it didn't go through.

Comment: @Barmar do you know another way to get the id of what u just inserted? :)

Comment: `$stmt->insert_id` does that. It has nothing to do with `store_result()`. BTW, it's not idiomatic to put spaces around `->`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas it makes the page go blank

Comment: @Barmar didn't make a difference :/

Comment: @Meek Which of my comments are you referring to when you say it didn't make a difference?

Comment: @Barmar both space and removed the store_result()

Comment: Both of those have no effect. The spaces are just coding style. `store_result()` doesn't do anything. But you're getting the error when you call `prepare()` and nothing in the `if` block is being executed, so why would you expect changing that code to make a difference?

Comment: @Barmar ah yeah lol ofc xD

Comment: @Barmar got back no database selected, I figured it out lol I did a stupid copy paste mistake somewhere, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Obviously you didn't.

Comment: @Barmar yeah hehe